# Which s3 compatible blob storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, glusterfs, cloud-storage, minio

I want deploy a s3 compatible blob storage in my Kubernetes Cluster. I already use GlusterFS for volumes like mongodb, and I tried to set up minio with the helm chart https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/minio. I just realize I can't scale up minio easily because of erasure code.

So I have some questions about blob storage solutions :

- Is GlusterFS blob storage service stable and reliable (https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/tree/master/docs/examples/gluster-s3-storage-template) ?
- Do I must use OpenShift to deploy GlusterFS blob storage as I read in the web ? I think no because I can see simple Kubernetes manifests in the GlusterFS repo like this one : https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/blob/master/deploy/kube-templates/gluster-s3-template.yaml.
- Is it easy to use Minio federation in Kubernetes ? Is it easily scalable with a "helm upgrade --set replicas=X" or do I need manually upgrade minio configuration ?

As you can see, I feel lost with this s3 storage. So if you have more information/solutions, do not hesitate.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

About reliability you should read more about user experience like:

- [An end user review of GlusterFS](https://www.tannerwilliamson.com/end-user-review-glusterfs-1362/)
- [Community Survey Feedback, 2019](https://www.gluster.org/community-survey-feedback-2019/)

Why [openshift with glusterFS](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_glusterfs.html#insta):

> For standalone Red Hat Gluster Storage, there is no component installation required to use it with OpenShift Container Platform. OpenShift Container Platform comes with a built-in GlusterFS volume driver, allowing it to make use of existing volumes on existing clusters but Red Hat Gluster Storage is a commercial storage software product, based on Gluster.

How to [deploy it in AWS](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Install-Guide/Setup_aws/%20https://medium.com/searce/implement-aws-ecs-services-with-glusterfs-file-system-aaf521be56d3)

For minio please follow [official docs](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/minio#updating-minio-configuration-via-helm):

> ConfigMap allows injecting containers with configuration data even while a Helm release is deployed.
>
> To update your MinIO server configuration while it is deployed in a release, you need to
>
> - Check all the configurable values in the MinIO chart using helm inspect values stable/minio.
> - Override the minio_server_config settings in a YAML formatted file, and then pass that file like this `helm upgrade -f config.yaml stable/minio`.
> - Restart the MinIO server(s) for the changes to take effect

I didn't try but, but as per documentation:

> - For federation I can see additional environment variables in the [values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/6c0bb36ffbc40cd45ec072d01178b74cee8cc32d/stable/minio/values.yaml#L246).
> - In addition you should Run `MinIO in federated mode` [Federation Quickstart Guide](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-federation-quickstart-guide.html)

Here you can find differences between [google and amazon s3 sotrage](https://www.zenko.io/blog/four-differences-google-amazon-s3-api/) 
or [Cloud Storage interoperability](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability) from gcloud perspective.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you Hanx. I know GlusterFS and it is reliable in my opinion. But I would talk about GlusterFS S3, not GlusterFS. I don't want have buckets in a cloud provider. I already read the minio documentation about federation and yes, I know there are values to configure federation. But with the federation, I have to restart all minio pods with the new configuration if I update these values to add a new minio cluster.

Comment: If it's crucial than you can consider using [configmap or secrets as environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically) instead of using pure env varaibles `Mounted configmaps and secrets are updated automatically`. In addition I didn't use GlusterFS S3,